# How to print text in a specific position?

Tags: c, dos, conio

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dos.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define MAX 25

main(){
    int a[MAX],i,j,lvl=2,score=0;
    float time=1.0,speed;
    speed=time/lvl;

    clrscr();

    for(i=0;i<MAX;i++)
        a[i]=rand()%50+1;

    while(1){
        for(j=0;j<MAX;j++){
            gotoxy(a[j],1);
            printf("*");
            gotoxy(1,1);
            insline();
            sleep(speed);
            score++;
            gotoxy(57,1);
            clrscr();
            printf("%d",score);
            if(score==100)
                lvl++;
        }
    }
}
```

Hi i'm trying to print the score on the upper right corner of the screen using `gotoxy()`. I used `gotoxy(1,1)` to set the cursor position where blank line should be inserted using `insline()`. but everytime I printed the score on the screen, it's printing the score continous as shown below:

[image: DOS screenshot with scores repeating down the right side]

*emphasized text*s there other way to print the score and delete it on its last position when `insline()` inserts a new line so that the last score will not be printed on the screen but the current score only?

Comment: dos.h? conio.h? Do you come from the past?

Comment: ^^ I was going to comment same :D

Comment: nope but we are required:D

Answer (score 2):

You should use this function

```
WriteConsoleOutput(....);
```

Check it on MSDN

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687404(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I have C++ project for a game I cannot share more :)